# Any way to style child element of :nth-child(an + b) selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to adjust the colors of a nav menu to alternate between colors, using :nth-child(an + b). Only I don't want to style the nth-child itself, but the child anchor text inside of the selected `<li>`

The basic setup:

```
<ul class="color-text"> 
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The styling:

```
.color-text li:nth-child(7n + 1) { // I'm alternating between seven colors
  color: --1st-color;
}
```

I'm not using any actual values, as they're not important. The issue is I can't figure out how to target the child  of the selected

. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Went on MDN, W3Schools etc and can't seem to find a relevant tutorial.

```
.color-text li:nth-of-type(7n + 1) a {
  color: red;
}
```

I want to change the text color of the child anchor text of the selected `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the double quotes on the `class` attribute of `.color-text` will surely help.

Regarding `:nth-child(7a + 1)` formula: in specs the var is always `n` and I was never curious enough to try to change the letter. I might be wrong, but it appears not to work with `a`.

Here's a working example:

```css
.color-text li:nth-child(7n + 1) a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="color-text"> 
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It was just a typo on here, the actual code closes the quotes, and uses the correct iterator (n).

Hmmmm, I have that code typed *exactly* the same, but it's not working. Maybe it's because of the Wordpress nature of navigation links. Maybe I'll inspect the nav to make sure the hierarchy is what I remember. I'll report back. Thanks!

Comment: Use `.color-text li:nth-child(7n + 1) a:not(#_) {}`. Sounds like a classic case of insufficient specificity. @Joel.

Comment: Wow. So apparently the theme my client is using wraps the Content inside the `<a>` tag within a `<span>`, so I targeted that and it works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `:link` and `:visited` to `a` to override any other`a:link` and `a:visited` rules:

```
.color-text li:nth-child(7a + 1) a:link,
.color-text li:nth-child(7a + 1) a:visited { 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I know I have the correct selector, cause display: none; disappears the li, but I can't figure out how to access the color: property of the anchor.

Comment: This would exclude visited links, in case that is important.

Comment: well, I took it for obious that also according rules/selectors for `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active` would have to be added, but apparently that wasn't understood that way, so I am adding it now.

Comment: No, only :visited needs to be added, but that does mean duplicating the entire selector. And it may be obvious to experienced coders like you and me, but I reckon it's not all that obvious to most readers.